# How to include angular 4 app inside iframe in another app?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

How to include a angular app in a non-angular app by using a iframe? Must be able to use angular app through this iframe with all routing still working. Is it possible? or Am I thinking wrong? Feel free to correct me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iFrame is a complete DOM. As per MDN: Each embedded browsing context has its own session history and active document.

With that in mind, angular apps will work just fine inside an iFrame.

General syntax: `<iframe src="url_to_your_angular_app"></iframe>`

Read more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: I added iframe just like you suggested. It's working !!

Comment: is there a way to pass a value to the angular app? like querystring